# How does the result of this basic arithmetic calculation turns out like this?

Tags: math, numbers, hex, arithmetic-expressions

Pardon my newbie level question, but i've been wondering and also recounting to see why the result turns out to be like that?
I understand why the first row results in like that but the rest remain a mystery to me. I've been using calculator to help and also review some basics on hexadecimal arithmetic but i'm still lost. If anyone could please explain why the result became like that it'll be appreciated.
Thanks.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6cAW.png)

Comment: The plus-in-a-circle denotes xor, not addition

Comment: oh my god thank you for the help! i did not even realize that until now. thank you!